# PHPUnit and Zend_Session - testing setExpirationSeconds

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit, zend-session

I have a preDispatch plugin that sets setExpirationSeconds to a setting in my application.ini.

I am trying to write a PHPUnit test for this.  Is there a way I can get the Expiration Seconds to compare it to my application.ini setting?

Comment: you could check:  $_SESSION['__ZF']['Default']['ENT'];

Comment: Nice.  I should have checked the code for setExpirationSeconds and I could have figured this out myself.  If you post this post this as an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could access the Session variable used by Zend Session, to check if the correct time is passed to the object.

```
$_SESSION['__ZF']['Default']['ENT'];
```